# VBA Auto fill visible cells (filtered range) with xlFillSeries

Tags: vba, filter, excel

I want to fill in 2..N integer series into filtered/visible range.

This code fills in the series but ignores the filtered range:

```
COL_SID_CURRENT = 3
COL_SID_CURRENT_STR = "c"
ROW_LAST = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count

' Start the series with value 2 in cell "c2"
Cells(2, COL_SID_CURRENT).FormulaR1C1 = "2"

aRangeStr = "" & COL_SID_CURRENT_STR & "2"      ' -> "c2"
Range(aRangeStr).Select

aRangeStr = aRangeStr & ":" & COL_SID_CURRENT_STR & ROW_LAST      ' -> "c2:c24"
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range(aRangeStr),Type:=xlFillSeries
```

I've tried to add the `xlCellTypeVisible` into the code but none of my combinations worked:

```
Range(aRangeStr).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range(aRangeStr).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible), _
   Type:=xlFillSeries
```

Any hint how to fill the series only on filtered/visible cells?

Comment: I'm not sure it makes any sense to use `xlFillSeries` on a Filtered Range.  If you record a macro while using the Auto-fill in Filtered range you'll see that Excel doesn't even try to fill a series, but it will if your range is not filtered.  Can you explain your purpose?  I would imagine that whenever your filter would be next change that data created by your fill-series will not make much sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Autofill doesn't work on the filtered range but there is alternative. :)

**TRIED AND TESTED**

You can use this formula instead (I am assuming you are filtering on the basis of what is stored in Col A (See Sample Image)

I am adding + 1 as you are starting the series with value 2 in cell "c2"

```
=IF(A2="FILTER_TEXT",COUNTIF($A$2:A2,"FILTER_TEXT")+1,"")
```

[image]

And to adapt it to your example, use this code.

```
Sub Sample()
    COL_SID_CURRENT = 3
    COL_SID_CURRENT_STR = "c"

    ROW_LAST = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count

    ' Start the series with value 2 in cell "c2"
    Cells(2, COL_SID_CURRENT).Formula = "=IF(A2=""FILTER_TEXT"",COUNTIF($A$2:A2,""FILTER_TEXT"")+1,"""")"

    aRangeStr = "" & COL_SID_CURRENT_STR & "2"      ' -> "c2"

    aRangeStr = aRangeStr & ":" & COL_SID_CURRENT_STR & ROW_LAST      ' -> "c2:c24"
    Range(aRangeStr).Formula = "=IF(A2=""FILTER_TEXT"",COUNTIF($A$2:A2,""FILTER_TEXT"")+1,"""")"
End Sub
```

Please change "FILTER_TEXT" to the relevant text. Also you might need to change the Reference Range. Like I mentioned, I am assuming that the filter is based on Values in Col A.